# Azure REST API - getting identity data

Tags: rest, azure

In Amazon cloud API there is the possibility to get identity data, meaning data from the running instance - on which region it is, dns ....
is there the same option in Azure? as I am creating management system in which the server is installed on a virtual machine and I need to know to which region it is related, all this using REST API

Answer (score 0):

In Azure you can use Azure API Management REST API to get all sort of information for Azure:

ex:

Lists all of the resources in a subscription:

[https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resources?$top={top}$skiptoken={skiptoken}&$filter={filter}&api-version={api-version}](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%7Bsubscription-id%7D/resources?$top=%7Btop%7D$skiptoken=%7Bskiptoken%7D&$filter=%7Bfilter%7D&api-version=%7Bapi-version%7D)

For the complete documentation look at this page here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn776326.aspx

You can do similar things using Powershell scripts as well.

Comment: not really helpfull, as I need api to ask data on the virtual machine I am running , without knowing the resource group and instance name

Comment: What data do you need? This was just a sample. You can basically do anything with the Azure REST api

Comment: suppose that i am supplying some server which needs to be installed on azure virtual machine. I need to know the region in which the vm was configured without any configuration --> telling me the name of the resource group, instance name

Comment: you need to know the resource group and the subscription id and the vm name to be able to get detail info about the vm:  https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/{resource-group-name}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{vm-name}?api-version={api-version} https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt163682.aspx